# trying to get leiningen user profile to run clojure-1.5.0

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have both clojure-1.4.0 and clojure-1.5.0 installed and working correctly.  In my various project.clj files, I can set one or the other as a dependency, and leiningen picks up the stated version correctly.  When I am not in a project directory, then `lein repl` always runs clojure-1.4.0.  I tried to change the default by putting the following `profiles.clj` in my `~/.lein` directory:

```
{:user {:dependencies ^:replace [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.0"]]
        :plugins                [[lein-pprint "1.1.1"]]}}
```

but `lein repl`, when not in a project directory, still runs clojure-1.4.0, with a seemingly incorrect error message if I happen to run `lein repl` while in the `~/.lein` directory:

```
WARNING: user-level profile defined in project files.
```

I know that none of my project.clj files have a user profile in them since the following command prints nothing

```
find ~ -name project.clj -exec grep ":user" "{}" ';' -print 2> /dev/null
```

I know that leiningen is reading my profiles.clj file, since if I put an intentional syntax error in the file, I get an expected compiler exception.

I've read `lein help profiles` but can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

hints, please & thanks?

Comment: see https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/966 for more on this.

Comment: ahh, great.  Known issue -- i'll check the issue pages more often.

Comment: It just got fully fixed. We'll have to wait till the lein 2.1 release though :)