# How to configure leiningen to use newest Clojure version for repl started outside of project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I start clojure repl for specific project, for leiningen is enough to specify correct clojure version in the concrete **project.clj** file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135440/lein-clojure-1-3-vs-clojure-1-2-1). But when I start repl outside the project then the older version is started. In my case  the older version is *1.5.1* and I want to upgrade to *1.6.0*. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329222/trying-to-get-leiningen-user-profile-to-run-clojure-1-5-0) has proposed not working solution, but in the comments bellow is said that in lieingen version *2.1* the problem is resolved. I'm with version *2.3.4* of leiningen but the proposed solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you're starting leiningen outside of a project, would it be better to simply start Clojure directly?  Startup will be faster.  You could write a one-line script to do this, and even wrap it in a command line history utility such as rlwrap (which isn't as nice as the one that Leiningen uses, however).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
according to technomancy on IRC: "repls outside projects are hard coded 
to lein's version of clojure"
```

Source: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1035#issuecomment-35927505

Comment: Is this means that the problem eventually will be resolved with the next version of leiningen ?

Comment: I don't know about Phil's priorities but seeing that this has been a problem since several versions back I'd say it's not the highest item on the list. Maybe ping him on IRC or comment on one of the fitting issues?